# Load Balancing among multiple virtual network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking

I have an AWS instance with multiple virtual network interfaces all having different elastic IPs. Since I crawl from this machine, the IPs often get blocked. Distributing the outgoing traffic through all these interfaces will prevent it since all are mapped to different elastic IPs.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:E6:A3:DD:F1:E0  
          inet addr:10.0.0.120  Bcast:10.0.0.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::8e6:a3ff:fedd:f1e0/64 Scope:Link

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:E6:A3:DD:F1:E0  
          inet addr:10.0.0.122  Bcast:10.0.0.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:E6:A3:DD:F1:E0  
          inet addr:10.0.0.18  Bcast:10.0.0.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I want to send my outgoing traffic from all the network interfaces in a round robin fashion. Since these are virtual interfaces I can't achieve this using the `iproute2` package. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Why can't you use the `iproute2` suite? All you need to do is change the default route.

Comment: @Patrick: Actually whenever i try to create a new routing table(alternate) and add a route saying `ip route add default dev eth0:0 table alternate`, it picks eth0 instead of eth0:0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `iproute2` suite for this. The fact that the source IPs are assigned to interface aliases has no impact on the issue.

Lets assume your default gateway is 10.0.0.1

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.122
```

That's it. Just replace the default route with the second line, replacing `10.0.0.122` with the source IP you want to route traffic out of.

---

If you want to use all your IPs at the same time, just assign them each certain subnets instead:

```
ip route add 64.0.0.0/2 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.122
ip route add 128.0.0.0/2 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.18
```

This will make any outbound traffic to `64.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255` use `10.0.0.122`, and `128.0.0.0 - 191.255.255.255` use `10.0.0.18`. All other traffic will use the default of `10.0.0.120`

---

The fact that the IPs are assigned to interface aliases (eth0:0) has absolutely no impact. IProute2 (or really the kernel) doesn't care.
*And yes, I tried this on my home network, it works just fine.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply but in this case you are hardcoding the destination ips . I dont want to do that .. I want to say lets say packet 1 to IP 1.1.1.1 through eth0:0 and packet 2 to IP 1.1.1.1 through eth0:1

Comment: Thank you patrick for your answer. I modified the ip route command to use source port instead of destination ip as the method of load balancing.